# Prevent Go modules from overwriting direct dependency version due to indirect import of same dependency

Tags: go, module, dependencies, project

I have a Go mods project with the following dependencies:

```
module github.com/owner0/my-project

go 1.15

require (
    github.com/owner1/projectA v1.0.0
    github.com/owner2/projectB v0.5.0
)
```

However the `github.com/owner1/projectA v1.0.0` dependency itself requires `github.com/owner2/projectB v0.8.0` (notice the higher version `v0.8.0` instead of `v0.5.0` as in my project):

```
github.com/owner1/projectA

go 1.15

require (
    github.com/owner2/projectB v0.8.0
)
```

This causes my current project to actually change and pull `github.com/owner2/projectB v0.8.0` instead of `github.com/owner2/projectB v0.5.0`, resulting in:

```
module github.com/owner0/my-project

go 1.15

require (
    github.com/owner1/projectA v1.0.0
    github.com/owner2/projectB v0.8.0
)
```

Is there a way to not allow `github.com/owner1/projectA v1.0.0` to overwrite the second dependency with a newer version? I want to keep `v0.5.0` despite the first dependency requiring `v0.8.0`.

Comment: You can try to `replace` it, but that means the other project needs to be able to build with v0.5.0 too. There's probably a reason they require v0.8.0.

Comment: A hacky way would be to add

`replace github.com/owner2/projectB/v05 => github.com/owner2/projectB v0.5.0` 

in go.mod file and change all import paths in your project (direct dependency) to "github.com/owner2/projectB/v05" instead of "github.com/owner2/projectB".